# Drupal Commerce Paypal: Order information at Paypal

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce paypal. When a client is directed to the paypal site, then by default this information is shown: Order  at .

How can I configure the information shown here?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to change that is through an alter hook documented in the module commece_paypal_wps.